# Checking null object from JSON response in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following code, and it works. I am checking if a JSON object has a full field and does not contain the underlying fields (Jira API, if you're interested). Is there a more concise way of writing the for loop?

```
myResponse = requests.get(url,auth=(urlUser,urlPass))

jd = myResponse.json()
myVals = jd['issues']

print(myVals[0].keys())
for issue in myVals:
    if issue['fields']['assignee'] is not None:
        assignee = issue['fields']['assignee']['displayName']
    else:
        assignee = "Unassigned"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) with fallback dictionary:

```
>>> issues = {'fields': {'assignee': None}}
>>> issues['fields']['assignee'] or {}  # fallback to an empty dictionary
{}
>>> (issues['fields']['assignee'] or {}).get('displayName', 'Unassigned')
'Unassigned'
```

---

```
for issue in myVals:
    assignee = (issue['fields']['assignee'] or {}).get('displayName', 'Unassigned')
```

OR define fallback dictionary like below:

```
UNASSIGNED = {'displayName': 'Unassigned'}
for issue in myVals:
    assignee = (issue['fields']['assignee'] or UNASSIGNED)['displayName']
```

Comment: The following code worked perfectly. I'm assuming the two methods are a matter of preference?

`for issue in myVals:
    assignee = (issue['fields']['assignee'] or {}).get('displayName', 'Unassigned')`